# How to Retrieve datetimepicker value from mysql back to datetimepicker of my c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

So i have a datetimepicker inside my Windows Form Application (C#)

(variable name = birthdatepPicker) CustomFormat : "MM - dd - yyy".

I successfully insert it in MySql Database using (this.birthdatePicker.Text)

Column Name = birthday and DataType = (VARCHAR(45)).

actually .. the one that retrieves the values from my database is a combobox which is inside my groupbox..

My Question. How can I retrieve the data of my datetimepicker that is saved from MySql back to my datetimepiker.

```
          string connect = "server=localhost;port=3307;username=root;password=keepthepromise";
          string query = "select * from database.employeeinfo where first_name='"+ select_update_combox.Text+"' ;";

          MySqlConnection connecttodtb = new MySqlConnection(connect);
          MySqlCommand querycmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connecttodtb);
          MySqlDataReader reader;

          try
          {
              connecttodtb.Open();
              reader = querycmd.ExecuteReader();

              while (reader.Read())
              {
                  string empID = reader.GetString("employeeID");
                  string user = reader.GetString("username");
                  string password = reader.GetString("password");
                  string conpass = reader.GetString("password");
                  string nameNdFN = reader.GetString("first_name");
                  string middlename = reader.GetString("middle_name");
                  string lastname = reader.GetString("last_name");
                  string birthday = reader.GetString("birthday");
                  string gender1 = reader.GetString("gender");
                  string email = reader.GetString("email");
                  string address1 = reader.GetString("address");


                  //------------------------------------------------

                  regEmpID_text.Text = empID;
                  reguser_txt.Text = user;
                  regpass_txt.Text = password;
                  regconpass_txt.Text = password;
                  regname_txt.Text = nameNdFN;
                  regmiddlename_txt.Text = middlename;
                  reglastname_txt.Text = lastname;


                  regaddress_txt.Text = address1;
                  regemail_txt.Text = email;
```

Comment: why i always have a -1 rating =_= .. what's the matter with my question?

Comment: .. sorry bout that. fixing it now. is this still unclear? .. I'm just a student btw..

Comment: so what is the appropriate data type for my birthday column?

Comment: I change its datatype to DATE..because I only want the date.. 

 so , now .. how can I retrieve it? back to my datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't change the data type on the birthday column in your database, you'll have to parse the string back into a valid DateTime using code like the following:

```
DateTime birthday;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(reader.GetString("birthday"), "MM dd yyyy",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out birthday))
{
    birthdatepPicker.Value = birthday;
}
```

Since you were able to change the type to a DateTime, you should just be able to read it back out:

```
birthdatepPicker.Value = reader.GetDateTime("birthday");
```

Comment: i have another problem now.. when I insert my datetimepicker to my MySql .. theres an error : Incorrect Date Value : 11/7/1996 12:00:00 AM for column 'birthday' at row 1 .. how can I solve this? please help ..

Comment: nvm of my last problem, i just forgot about the right format..
@Gran Winney .. Thanks ^^ you help a lot ..